# Why do I get different results with the same code in Python?

Tags: python, boolean

```
L = [1,2,3]

print(len(L) == 3 & len(L) > 2)
print(len(L) > 2 & len(L) == 3)
```

^^ the top one evaluates to true and the bottom one evaluates to false? Why? Aren't they the same thing?

Comment: You want `and`, not `&`.

Comment: `&` has higher precedence than the comparison operators. The result is `len(L) == (3 & len(L)) > 2`, not `(len(L) == 3) & (len(L) > 2)`.

Answer (score 4):

To explain in more detail: `&` performs a bitwise comparison, but it also has higher precedence than the relational operators (unlike the logical `and`).

```
len(L) == 3 & len(L) > 2
```

This compares `len(L) == (3 & len(L))` as well as `(3 & len(L)) > 2` ([chained relational operators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons) - the `3 & len(L)` is only evaluated once). Since `len(L)` is equal to 3, `3 & len(L)` evaluates to 3 as well (bitwise AND). `3 == 3` and `3 > 2`, so this is true.

```
len(L) > 2 & len(L) == 3
```

Similarly: `2 & len(L)` evaluates to 2. `2 > 2` is false (and for good measure, `2 == 3` is also false), so this evaluates false.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to use `&` for the logical `AND` operator, use the word `and`:

```
>>> L = [1,2,3]
>>> print(len(L) == 3 and len(L) > 2)
>>> print(len(L) > 2 and len(L) == 3)
True
True
```